# Mysql query to find rows based on substring left() and column max() value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

If having the following dataset:

```
Fqdn         RefQty
abcde.com    25
abcdz.uk     10
abcdf.es     15
bcdef.fr     30
bcdeg.de     25
bcdeh.ch     50
```

In MySQL how to select in order to have the Fqdn where the LEFT(Fqdn,4) has the MAX(RefQty)?
I can find the LEFT(Fqdn,4) with MAX(RefQty) but when selecting Fqdn I don't get the right Fqdn? In this case my answer would be:

```
Fqdn
abcde.com
bcdeh.ch
```

This seemed trivial but somehow I'm stuck for several hours on this. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find max counts for trimmed strings in the inner query and use those counts in the outer query while joining.

```
SELECT T.Fqdn
FROM
YOUR_TABLE T
INNER JOIN
(SELECT LEFT(Fqdn, 4) Fqdn_Trim, MAX(RefQty) as MAX_COUNT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY LEFT(Fqdn, 4)) A
ON LEFT(T.Fqdn, 4) = A.Fqdn_Trim AND T.RefQty = A.MAX_COUNT
ORDER BY T.RefQty DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks Vashi. On first run I thought the results were not OK as they were "incomplete" looking at the first ~100, but then I added "order by t.RefQty desc" and confirm that the result is OK. On a 250k row, I get the result dataset (120k rows) in 3.5 seconds. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I have added the `ORDER BY` clause for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a left join with itself: it looks for all Fqdns that do not have another row with the same Fqdn but a higher RefQty. This must be the rows with the highest RefQty:

```
SELECT
  t1.Fqdn
FROM
  mytable AS t1 LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON (LEFT(t1.Fqdn, 4) = LEFT(t2.Fqdn, 4) AND 
                                            t1.RefQty < t2.RefQty)
WHERE
  t2.Fqdb IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Looked promissing as simple solution, but when running SQL "EXPLAIN" I get "Range checked for each record (index map: 0x8); Not exists" and get 227332 rows for each match, making the query too long to run.